# Testing DC motor with a torque wrench

Tags: dc-motor, torque

How can I measure the torque of a stalled DC motor @ 6V using a torque wrench? I'm trying to test my DC motor with the torque wrench method (regular torque wrench used for cars).

Comment: Is this a mechanical problem of interfacing?

Comment: You can't. A 6V motor is far too low torque to register on a mechanic torque wrench. Use a lever stick with weights. Don't forget to add in the weight of the stick located at the COG.

Comment: If you know the motor part number, finding the stall torque is a simple matter of reading the datasheet.

Comment: I'm trying to test the torque spec from the datasheet. My professor was suggesting a test using a torque wrench, but I wasn't sure how to do this. But yeah, the torque of a small motor is very low (about 30oz in) , so I don't think I could do it with a Torque wrench. I will test it with an allen wrench

Comment: You could get a cheap torque measuring screwdriver and connect that to the shaft of the motor.  Or you could make your own: it's basically a torsion spring with a pointer and dial on it.

Comment: You can also just put a bolt stick to the shaft put it under an electronic scale. Make sure the angle is 90 degrees so it is pushing straight down.

Comment: A metal link chain can be an easy start. For a known arm length you can support torque = links X link_weight X arm length. Place chain on a lowerable surface and adjust height until chIn  neither drags arm down nor is pulled up - arm horizontal and static gives torque.

Comment: Does anyone know if to get the transversal arm connector for the shaft, could I get that at Home Depot or something? Not sure how what to add to the shaft to include an allen wrench. Was thinking something like an adjustable antenna female connector that would go to the shaft, and then adding something to hold the transversal arm?
I'll try the chain idea too

Answer (score 0):

If you can attach a really light but stiff rod to the shaft, to act as a lever, then you can slide a known mass, say \$m=0.1kg\$, along the rod until the motor is *just* able to lift the mass.

Measure the distance \$d\$ (in metres) between the motor shaft and mass. Then torque \$\tau\$ is:

$$ \tau = m \times g \times d $$

where acceleration due to gravity \$g=9.8Nkg^{-1}\$.

If your measurement units are metres and kilograms, then the result you get is newton-metres, \$\text{Nm}\$.